# Oblique div not properly transforming?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have an oblique div created with   transform: skewY(-10deg);
But i can't center it on the top of the page with the instruction top:%.

It is not working responsively.

How do I get this to work?

With top:0 and left:0:

[image]

With top:-135px:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean 'center it on the top of the page'?

Comment: Where is the (tagged) PHP-part of your question?

Comment: Removed unnecessary tags. Included a clearer title. Please include an image of what you are trying to accomplish as you might get more responses if users know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Added the images instead of offsite links.

Comment: Do you want a triangle on top left or do you want both screenshot a triangle and a vertical div ?

Comment: I want to do this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9IXI.png

Comment: Then try my answer with triangle-div you will not need to use skewY with it. It's working for me

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the css of the element `triangle-div` to the below.

```
#triangle-div{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid red;
    border-right: 200px solid transparent;
    position: fixed
}
```

Comment: You can still expand your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please provide as jsfiddle or an image of what you are trying to achieve - It is unclear what you want.

However, to position the div centrally:

```
div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9IXI.png I want to do this but i can't do this whit top:-135px becouse the responsive not work, there is the code compiled: http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/msypboln